# I want to be able to update two list boxes at the same time with two searchbars

Tags: python, tkinter, listboxitem

I want to be able to update two list boxes at the same time with two lists that have the same number of items from two search bars. The fist list box has a list with letters, and the second list box has numbers that correspond directly to those letters so like A goes with 1, B goes with 2 and so on. I want to be able to type 'a' in the first entry box on the left and have only the 'a' show up in the first list box and only '2' in the second, or type in a '2' in the second box which will show all the items that have a '2' in the second list box, and so that the first list box also show only the items that correspond to this items. I have already been able to make it so that one entry box can do with but with only one of the two list boxes, but I want both to update at the same time.

```
from tkinter import *  # allows for the use of tkinter GUI

win = Tk()  # creates the tkinter window
win.title("test")  # sets the name of the window
win.geometry("1100x700")  # sets the size of the window
win.resizable(False, False)  # prevents the window from being resized

# these are made up lists for this question
databaselist1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18'
                 , '19', '20']
databaselist2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T']


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  this section synchronizes the mouse scrolled for both list boxes
def scroll2(event):
    IDsearchresultslist.yview_scroll(int(-4 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")  # makes it so that when the user scrolls
    # though one list box, all the list boxes scroll as well


def scroll1(event):
    alphabetlist.yview_scroll(int(-4 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")  # makes it so that when the user scrolls
    # though one list box, all the list boxes scroll as well


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def checkinlist1(e):  # uses the characters typed in their specifically typed order into the ID search entry box in
    # order to display the results that have those characters into the search
    # result box or in other words, an autofill function
    searchtyped = IDsearchEntry.get().replace("'", "`")  # looks at the characters that are being typed into
    # the ID search entry box
    if searchtyped == ' ':  # checks if nothing is typed into the ID search entry box
        listdata1 = databaselist1  # makes it so that the entire list is displayed into the search results box
    else:  # this happens if the ID search entry box has something typed in it
        listdata1 = []
        for item in databaselist1:  # loops though the list
            if searchtyped.lower() in item.lower():
                listdata1.append(item)
    update1(listdata1)  # updates listdata each time the code loops through the checkinlist function


def checkinlist2(e):  # uses the characters typed in their specifically typed order into the nsearch entry box in order
    # to display the results that have those characters into the search result box or in other words
    # , an autofill function

    searchtyped = nsearchentry.get().replace("'", "`")  # looks at the characters that are being typed into the
    # nsearch entry box
    if searchtyped == ' ':  # checks if nothing is typed into the nsearch entry box
        listdata2 = databaselist2  # makes it so that the entire list is displayed into the alphabet listbox
    else:  # this happens if the nsearch entry box has something typed in it
        listdata2 = []
        for item in databaselist2:  # loops though the list
            if searchtyped.lower() in item.lower():
                listdata2.append(item)
    update2(listdata2)  # updates listdata each time the code loops through the checkinlist function


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# this section sets up the list boxes
alphabetframe = Frame(win)  # creates the frame that will contain the scrollbar for the alphabetframe

IDsearchresultslist = Listbox(win, width=39, font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'))  # creates the

# of the listbox
# ID search list box that will contain the

IDsearchresultslist.place(relx=.6, rely=.15)  # moves the ID search results box to its location

# this section creates the first buttons that will show up when the program is opened
alphabetlist = Listbox(alphabetframe, width=50, font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'))  # creates the search entry box

# of the listbox
alphabetframe.place(relx=.05, rely=.2)  # moves the frame that contains the scrollbar to its location

alphabetlist.pack(pady=15, padx=15)

alphabetlist.bind("<MouseWheel>", scroll2)  # when the mousewheel is used, the scroll2
# function with be activated
IDsearchresultslist.bind("<MouseWheel>", scroll1)  # when the mousewheel is used, the scroll1
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# this section creates the two entry boxes that will control what the user searches for
IDsearchEntry = Entry(win, width=20, font=('Arial', 15, 'bold'))  # creates the ID search entry box
IDsearchEntry.bind("<KeyRelease>", checkinlist1)  # binds the action of the user clicking on an entry from the list box
# in order for an action to happen
IDsearchEntry.place(relx=.717, rely=.07)  # moves the ID search entry box to its location

nsearchentry = Entry(win, width=17, font=('Arial', 15, 'bold'))  # sets up the nsearch entry box and its parameters
nsearchentry.bind("<KeyRelease>", checkinlist2)  # binds the action of the user clicking on an entry from the list box
# in order for an action to happen
nsearchentry.place(relx=.29, rely=.553)  # moves the nsearchentry box to its location


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# this section updates the listboxes though their list
def update1(listdata1):  # this function updates the list that shows up inside the IDsearchresultslist as the user types
    IDsearchresultslist.delete(0, END)  # clears the listbox, if END doesn't work use "end"
    for item in listdata1:  # loops though the list
        IDsearchresultslist.insert(END, item)  # moves each individual item from the list into the listbox
        # as the list gets looped


def update2(listdata2):  # this function updates the list that shows up inside the nresultslist as the user types
    alphabetlist.delete(0, END)  # clears the listbox, if END doesn't work use "end"
    for item in listdata2:  # loops though the list
        alphabetlist.insert(END, item)  # moves each individual item from the list into the listbox
        # as the list gets looped


update1(databaselist1)  # makes the databaselist go through the update function
update2(databaselist2)  # makes the databaselist go through the update function

win.mainloop()


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzRT1.png
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you use classes your code will be half as long.

Comment: btw you have to understand that you don't need to  comment what code does, that should be understandable from the code itself, comment why and maybe how it does it or use comments for section management or sth, most of your comments are useless. Other thing is that don't import everything from a module unless you know what you are doing (basically don't use `*` when importing). An exception would be if you wrote that module yourself, then at least you know what is inside of it or can easily check. Either use: `import tkinter` (`as tk` could be used) or `from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label..`

Comment: Yea I still have a lot to learn. I also forgot that classes are a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to zip the lists containing the data, add elements to the list and pass it to `update(x)()` function.

The `zip()` function will get the elements of similar indexes from multiple containers.

And since you want to update it correspondingly, that is the way to go.

```
def checkinlist1(e):  
    ....
        listdata1 = []
        listdata2=[]
        for item,item2 in zip(databaselist1,databaselist2):  # loops though the list
            if searchtyped.lower() in item.lower():
                listdata1.append(item)
                listdata2.append(item2)
    update2(listdata2)
    update1(listdata1)

....
def checkinlist2(e):  
        ....
        listdata2 = []
        listdata1=[]
        for item,item2 in zip(databaselist2,databaselist1):  # loops though the list
            if searchtyped.lower() in item.lower():
                listdata2.append(item)
                listdata1.append(item2)
    update1(listdata1) 
    update2(listdata2)
```

References:
[zip() function in python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python/)